How to optimize a log load from an API in Laravel?
I don't have code yet, but basically, it is a load of records to several tables in the database. For that a cron task was going to be used.
In this load of records, each record they have has its API for its personalized information, so it would be to visit 20,000 APIS and fill several tables with each API, what would be the best way to do it in terms of execution speed? I know the question is somewhat brief or without context, but what I would need most is an idea to make the code.
The only thing I could think of was to do a foreach and go API by API, but I don't know if it's the best, or if it can be done asynchronously
Thank you very much in advance
çHow to run a code that reads thousands of records from an API as optimally as possible

I think the best for execution speed is to break it up in chunks and queue all the chunks in the job queue (see https://laravel.com/docs/11.x/queues) With enough queue workers you can achieve a great deal of parallelism (assuming your server can handle that). You can use something like supervisor to configure multiple queue workers
